# ngrx import in angular application

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to import NGRX to build a new Angular application but i have this error in my terminale when i use ng serve:

ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:99 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;
~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:118 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;

This Is my angular cli  /  node version / OS
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 10.13.0
OS: darwin x64

Answer (score 6):

NgRx v11 expects TypeScript 4 to be used and Angular 11. https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v11

Answer (score 3):

Downgrade the @ngrx/store to 10.2.1 or lower version.

cmd: yarn add @ngrx/store@10.2.1

If you are using npm then

cmd: npm install @ngrx/store@10.2.1

Comment: For some reason, 10.2.1 refused to install for me with Angular CLI 9.1.12 & Typescript 3.8.3.   @ngrx/store@10.1.2 worked okay though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall or delete  the node modules and again reinstall node modules through the **npm install** or  **ng serve**. the nodemodules will be installed again, now try to run the error will be resolved.