# Ngrx StoreModule declaration forRoot error Angular 9

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Only by declaring the StoreModule on the code below:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({})
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm having the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:99 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;
                                                                                                     ~
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/reducer_creator.d.ts:32:118 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

32 export declare function on<State, Creators extends readonly ActionCreator[]>(...args: [...creators: Creators, reducer: OnReducer<State, Creators>]): ReducerTypes<State, Creators>;
```

Even if I create a reducer and declare it within the method, the error persists
Any idea how to solbe this?

Thanks by now

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2924. Someone solved it downgrading to `@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2` but at the end it seems related to the version of your typescript, angular and/or ngrx in general:

> ...in all of the cases the culprit was a lower version of TypeScript.
> If this issue is reproducible with the latest angular version, and the
> latest ngrx version, feel free to reopen (or create a new) this issue
> with the reproduction.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238212/ngrx-import-in-angular-application) they say:

> NgRx v11 expects TypeScript 4 to be used and Angular 11.

Comment: I changed the version here of the package and apparently it solved the problem, thank you so much for the answer!